# Pass string information from Fragment to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I am using `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` to uninstall packages and am trying to retrieve the application name of the removed package after it is removed. I can only seem to get the package name. I cannot use `ApplicationInfo` on the package name since the package is already gone. I tried passing the value into the intent but since it goes to another activity that is not owned by me `UninstallerActivity` it is not there. I couldn't figure out how to pass the string into the IntentFilter data field since I need to use it for package name. I am not using `sendBroadcast` so I cannot use that.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+packageName));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED");
            intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");

            mContext.registerReceiver(mUninstallReceiver, intentFilter);
            startActivity(intent);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mUninstallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action != null) {

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)) {
           Uri intentData = intent.getData();
           //the above only contains package name
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**How do I pass the application name to this broadcast receiver?**

**Update**

I ended up just using a member variable which isn't what I totally wanted, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I pass the application name to this broadcast receiver?

- Define your own custom subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`, where you supply a `PackageManager` to the constructor
- Have that constructor gather whatever information it needs from the `PackageManager`
- Create an instance of that `BroadcastReceiver` *before* you call `startActivity()`
- Hold onto that `BroadcastReceiver` object somewhere so you can unregister it as soon as you receive your broadcast
- If there is a possibility that the user might request to uninstall 2+ apps before the first uninstall completes, have `onReceive()` confirm that the broadcast it received is for the package it is tracking, as with this plan, you will have 2+ `BroadcastReceiver` objects outstanding at any point in time

There are other possible ways of organizing this (e.g., `Map` of package name to data, so you only need one receiver), but they will all be along the same lines: collect the data you need before you uninstall, so that you have the data by the time you receive the broadcast.